# Why duplicate version on two servers but one send error Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have production and development server, both use the same database and codes. However when it execute this part of the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        //if the user related to a company or not

        SqlConnection myConnection01 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
        SqlCommand myCommand01 = new SqlCommand("UserCompany", myConnection01);
        myCommand01.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parameterUserCompany01 = new SqlParameter("@FromEmail", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100);
        parameterUserCompany01.Value = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        myCommand01.Parameters.Add(parameterUserCompany01);

        SqlParameter parameterUserCompany02 = new SqlParameter("@CountUser", SqlDbType.Int);
        parameterUserCompany02.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        myCommand01.Parameters.Add(parameterUserCompany02);

        myConnection01.Open();
        myCommand01.ExecuteReader();
```

the production server can execute without any problem, but the development server gives this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

There is only minor difference in two DBs. One include some different records from the others. But I tried on the same records it still show that error.
I do not know how to debug this error?

Comment: Fire up SQL server profiler and run your application. Run the Stored proc with parameters logged in profiler in `SSMS`, you will find the issue. This issue is `SQL` related and not your C# code related. This happens when you expect single value from query but query returns more than one record.

Comment: I find the record in the DB but can find only one record, how could it be more than one record? I am not very sure how to execute your suggestion ?

Comment: It's the problem with your SP only. If possible show your stored proc, You must be having something like this in your SP: `SET @foo = (SELECT foo From bar WHERE x = 1)` which is causing this issue. Also, I am talking about `SQL Server Profiler` tool, its really helpful and easy tool, do some research on it.

Comment: I see, there are so many SP in my DB, I don't think it is useful to share them, is there any way to search to the point you suspect ?

Comment: Btw, most of the SPs in Dev server are also in Prod server, why it won't cause the same error ?

Comment: Because it depends on the data, your SP might be same in both environments but data may differ. If you're sure it is caused by above code then check that specific SP line by line with sample data.

Comment: There is a store procedure in the code I post above, when I go to its definition I found:  //The name of a stored procedure.
        StoredProcedure = 4, What does that mean? How could I find the code of this storedprocedure ?

Comment: It's really tough to answer that, `StoredProcedure ` must be a variable in your SP.

Comment: Can you share the source of stored procedure?

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your comments and suggestion, I found out the problem is there are two user with the same user's email addresses in my db. That is the one that cause the problem, thanks @Rahul Singh for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting [user1314404](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314404/user1314404)

> I found out the problem is there are two user with the same user's
>   email addresses in my db.

That is the one that cause the problem.

Always double-check duplicates (**indices**, **keys** or columns you want to index) in your database before questioning the query,  especially when you have **different results** with **different databases**.